# bxSlider display photos in the correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

Photos are loading from DB MVC5, so I have one boxslider for photos and one pager for their little coppies as clickable preview. It works, but not correctly, if I click on the preview, it shows not right photo (usually one more or stops working at all). 
**HTML:**

```
    <div class="slideimg">
    <ul class="bxslider2 bxslider-mobile">
        @foreach (GalleryModel gal in Model.Gallery)
        {
            <li><img style="width: 1050px;" src="@($"data:image;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(gal.Image)}")"/></li>
        }
    </ul>
    <div class="pager" style="height: 500px">
        <div id="bx-pager">
            @{
                int a = 1; //z-order 
            }
            @foreach (GalleryModel gal in Model.Gallery)
            {

                <a data-slide-index=@a href=""><img src="@($"data:image;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(gal.Image)}")" /></a>
                a++;
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This how it looks after adding 3 photos from db:
[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WHoZ.png)

I think maybe something should be changed with z-order of pager.

Comment: Disable the `infiniteLoop` from bxslider will help you.

Comment: @JitendraYadav thank you! Love so much to work with unknown options.